# Geogebra special segment construction

Tags: geometry, math-software

Could someone help me constructing such segment AB in Geogebra that would satisfy such properties:

1. by moving the point A the segment moves as a solid body but does not rotate
2. by moving the point B the segment changes its orientation and size
3. the segment should be able to move like a solid body even if one of its edge points is attached to a line

I have already tried to use vectors but got the result that don't satisfy those properties above.

Comment: Did you know that when you hover your mouse over segment and then press left mouse button, you are able to move that segment as a solid body?

Comment: Yes, but when I pin one of a segment points to a line, the segment is not alowed to move like that anymore

Comment: It is true. Well, that is a main property/purpose of pinning/fixing of some object(s)...

Comment: Should I modify my question by specifying this condition about pinning a point to a line?

Comment: Draw segment $AB$ as usual, then in the settings of $A$, tab "Advanced", deselect the "Selection allowed" button.

Comment: It doesn't solve the problem when I pin a point (A as in your advise) to a line. It just disables the point A to be selected. I want to be able to move the segment like a solid body even if one of its points is attached to a line

Comment: The [r/geogebra](https://reddit.com/r/geogebra/) subreddit on Reddit serves as the app's help forum. Perhaps asking there would be prudent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the [red segment in this Geogebra demo](https://www.geogebra.org/classic/a3juct9z) I made. I think it does exactly what you want.

Click on point I or J with the settings menu open and look at the "On Update" tab under the "Scripting" tab. The script is SetValue(J, I+(x(L)-x(K),y(L)-y(K))) for point I, the one that moves the segment as a whole and SetValue(J, I+(x(L)-x(K),y(L)-y(K))) for point J that is free to move. Dragging point J alters a hidden segment (K,L) that acts as the memory.

There are some other segments in that demo with different scripts (Some under the "On drag" menu tab) just for demonstration purposes of what is possible.